# AsyncTask crashs during execution

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So if I start my **`AsyncTask`** it just crashes while calling the method `getXmlFromUrl`. I dont find a solution, can anyone help me? I am trying around for an hour or something... It says there is a missing `catch` block, but where?
If I comment the `getXmlFromUrl` the app just works fine.
I came to an end, so any help would be fine :)

**Source:** http://pastebin.com/347ayn6W

**Errors:** http://pastebin.com/AA3W7e4F

Comment: Don't use pastebin, post your code, and format it in here please :)

Comment: But the source is some 100 lines long.... it would be to long to post here, since i did not saw any spoiler function

Comment: Does not matter how long it is. Just format the code as code, and it will be wrapped in a scroller. If your links die, this question will be bad for other if they are looking for help on similar problems!

Answer (score 3):

Simply: You can't do View stuff in AsyncTask `doInBackground()` Method.
Just move your call   `p.dismiss();` to `onPostExecute()`
onPostExecute is also a Method you need to override from AsyncTask-Class:

```
onPostExecuted(Void nothing)
{
 p.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: OMG!! i missed the internet permission -.- thank you! your point was true as well :) i am a newbie and i am still learning :) startet coding android in late november, and never used java before, just c++, php, autoit and a small look at objective-c with a big big smile, because obj.-c is crap :D

Answer (score 1):

```
p.dismiss();
```

don't dissmis your progressdialog in doInBackground() method. you should do it onPostExecute() method

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

```
01-18 12:58:39.086: E/AndroidRuntime(16249): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Because you are dismissing `ProgressDailog dialog` in `doInBackground()` of AsyncTask which is run in **WorkerThread**. While your `ProgressDailog dialog` is running on **ActivityMainThread**..

**And Android strictly not allowed to update any Views in Worker or any other Thread.**

Just remove   `p.dismiss();` from `doInBackground()` and put it in `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask

**Something Like:**

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... nothing){
 Globals.shopCon=new ShopConnection("http://" + Globals.ip + "/ws410/rest/");
 return null;                                   
}

onPostExecuted(Void nothing)
{
 p.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as in log :

> CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created
>   a view hierarchy can touch its views

because you are trying to dismiss  `ProgressDialog` in `doInBackground`. just move `p.dismiss()` inside `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0):

Find the new version of the code [here](http://pastebin.com/u0M2cRS9). You shouldn't dismiss progress dialog inside `doInBackground()`